# react-native sqlite runs only the first time

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite

I am trying two create two tables when the app launches. But only one table gets created for some reason. If I try to create one of the either table at a time it works fine.
So far what I can know is that both the queries are valid and they should be working because I tried creating both of those tables one by one after closing the app and launching again and creating another table. But I want both of the tables to created on app start. Here is my code

SqliteService.tsx

```
import { enablePromise, openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

const SQLiteService = () => {
  const getDBConnection = async () => {
    enablePromise(true)
    return openDatabase({ name: 'test.db', location: 'default' })
  }
  const createTable1 = async (db) => {
    const query = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_1 ('key' TEXT NOT NULL, 'value' TEXT NOT NULL);`
    await db.executeSql(query)
  }
  const createTable2 = async (db) => {
    const query = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_2 ('key' TEXT NOT NULL, 'value' TEXT NOT NULL);`
    await db.executeSql(query)
  }
  return {
    getDBConnection,
    createTable1,
    createTable2
  }
}
```

and in my App.tsx

```
const setupDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
  const db = await SQLiteService().getDBConnection()
  await SQLiteService().createTable1(db) // only this gets created
  await SQLiteService().createTable2(db)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setupDatabase()
}, [setupDatabase])
```

Any help on how to resolve this would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Both of your `createTable` functions create 'TABLE_1', is that a typo?

Comment: yes thats a typo. i will edit the question. thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question. This may not be the best way to do this, but I was able to resolve the issue. I had to create multiple promises and resolve all promises with `Promise.all()` with `await` so the tables get created first and access/insert the data later

`SqliteService.tsx`

```
import { enablePromise, openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage'

const SQLiteService = () => {
  const getDBConnection = async () => {
    return openDatabase({ name: 'test.db', location: 'default' })
  }
  const initializeDatabases = async (db) => {
    enablePromise(true)
    const table1Query = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_1 ('key' TEXT NOT NULL, 'VALUE' TEXT NOT NULL);`
    const table2Query = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_2 ('KEY' TEXT NOT NULL, 'value' TEXT NOT NULL);`
    const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.executeSql(table1Query, [], (rs) => resolve(rs), reject)
    })
    const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.executeSql(table2Query, [], (rs) => resolve(rs), reject)
    })
    const data = await Promise.all([a, b])
    return data
  }
  return {
    getDBConnection,
    initializeDatabases
  }
}
```

`App.tsx`

```
const setupDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
  const db = await SQLiteService().getDBConnection()
  SQLiteService().initializeDatabases(db)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  setupDatabase()
}, [setupDatabase])
```

The usage of `enablePromise(true)` is still not very clear to me. If anyone have a better solution please feel free to answer the question